# Pouvez-vous m'expliquer le rôle de " en " dans la phrase suivante ! Que remplace-t-il ici ?

Tags: grammaire, en

"Il observa le ventre de Sonja d’un air songeur, comme s’il s’attendait à en voir surgir un drapeau."

Je suis intéressé par la phrase "à en voir surgir".
Merci !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ici *en* remplace *le ventre de Sonja*. La deuxième partie de la phrase peut être reformulée comme suit :

> comme s'il s'attendait à voir un drapeau surgir **de son ventre**.

Comment: Le remplacement est vraiment celui de « de son ventre » (antécédent construit). (Il regarda la crème glacée de Sonja, comme s'il en voulait une. — Le remplacement est « crème glacée » dans ce cas-ci.)